# Javascript: .9 repeating not rounding to 1

Tags: javascript

This code usually works, converting a fractional score into a percentage with no decimal places:

`$('.correct_percent').contents().replaceWith(((Math.round((correctCount/questionsInRound)*100)/100) * 100) + '%');`

But when I try it where `questionsInRound` is 7 and `correctCount` is 4, I get 56.99999999999999%. I understand that floating point numbers are not precise, but is there a way around this? I considered using the `toFixed` method, but that would return 56% instead of 57%, and I feel like there might be a better way.

Comment: Why do you divide the rounded result by 100 and then multiply it by 100?  If I get rid of those, I end up with 57.

Comment: You can set the precision of `toFixed` like this:  `toFixed(2)` and that will produce `56.99`

Comment: toFixed() will round it for you

Comment: I think you've multiplied and divided by 100 a few too many times there.

Comment: toFixed does work, but then when I multiply by 100 my program freezes. This is really weird... I have to go to class but after that I'll try more of your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're taking the result from Math.round, and dividing it by 100; that's not guaranteed to leave you with a round number.

Have you tried this?

```
$('.correct_percent').contents().replaceWith(Math.round(correctCount*100/questionsInRound) + '%');
```

Seems simpler, and it seems to give the correct result.

Answer (score 3):

Math.round(4/7 * 100) returns 57.

Answer (score 0):

if score is the percentage then you can try

Math.floor(score*100+.5)

Comment: or if you want to be sneaky your answer can be rewritten as `~~(score+.5)*100`

Answer (score 0):

var percent = (correctCount / questionsInRound * 100).toFixed(0) + '%';